# Finding model for time series in R

Tags: r, regression, model, acf-pacf

I am supposed to find model for the following time series.
[image]

It looks to me that it has trend, so I tried regression, here is code:

```
t<-1:length(exchangeRate)
t2<-t*t
trend<-lm(exchangeRate~t+t2)
res<-residuals(trend)
```

Then I plotted residuals:
[image]

I see that residuals are autocorrelated, so I tried harmonic regression:

```
exchangeRate.per<-spec.pgram(res, log="no")
```

[image]

Clearly there is on significant frequency which is $0.01041667$, so my model should be the following:

```
cost<-cos(2*pi*1041667/100000000*t)
sint<-sin(2*pi*1041667/100000000*t)
sez<-lm(exchangeRate~t+t2+cost+sint)
```

And the I did residuals again:

```
resid2<-residuals(sez)
```

But from the ACF it is clear that residuals are still autocorrelated.

[image]

Can you tell me where I made mistake?

Comment: The code seems to indicate that the data is an exchange rate. Is that the case? If so, you need to apply some domain knowledge because what you've done so far is not compatible with commonly accepted facts about exchange rates.

Comment: @ChrisHaug yes it is. Can you tell me what I should apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, asset prices are very difficult to forecast. This is because of how future expectations about the price quickly feedback into the current price. For example, if you could easily forecast that the price was going to go up next year, everyone would buy now and the price would go up *now*, not later. Asset prices tend to react immediately to unpredictable news, rather than have long-term forecastable structure.

Exchange rates are not really different in that regard. For that reason:

1. Deterministic trends are not usually appropriate, especially a quadratic one.
2. Seasonality is not usually appropriate, either.

Unlike stocks and other assets where it's more obvious, the great debate concerning exchange rates is whether they are mean-reverting or not. Usually, something like an AR(1) with $\phi$ smaller than but near 1 if they are, or with $\phi=1$ (a random walk) if they aren't, possibly in logs, is  an appropriate simple model for an exchange rate.

From your final ACF chart, I would suggest you skip the time trend and the Fourier regressors and just try an AR(1), but the PACF would be more informative in that regard.

Comment: Thank you so much